# Strange syntax when conditional types are combined with mapped types

Tags: typescript

Here's the [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#example-1)

Here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsEAUBO7I6gByAhgLYQDOAPACoB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2gNJSoEUANYQQ6AGZRaAXQBc0vjKgQAHsAgIAJpViIUGIQH4o-BQggA3CDgDc7AL7dR4qbPvtBGnBJJJoWCSEbJwCWuZwZABGNvZcCOQQCpTAOIIA5nFQlHBRYEHAlAqBhNwyWXBgWiQaJcAAFBYA7qQUyakZAJQKluioWvYO7OygkNIAjMx6yGiYuPg2xIk0dfQeSJgpUGQgAGpBcrSTLADkldW1BSfsQA)

Here's the example's code:

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

interface Part {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  subparts: Part[];
  updatePart(newName: string): void;
}

type T1 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;

const myVar:T1 = 'updatePart'
```

I'm really confused about `[keyof T]` part in `type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {...}[keyof T]`. This is the first time I see such syntax and I couldn't find anything about it in the docs. Could you please give me another example of its use? Or maybe point me in the direction where I can read up on it. Or maybe give an insight on how it works.

Thank you, good sirs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`keyof T`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) is an expression which, when `T` is an object, evaluates to all the names of the properties in `T`. E.g.:

```
type Thing = { fieldOne: string; fieldTwo: number };

type ThingFields = keyof Thing; // equivalent to: type ThingFields = "fieldOne" | "fieldTwo"
```

The `FunctionPropertyNames<T>` utility is confusing but we can go through `FunctionPropertyNames<Part>` step by step to see how it evaluates into `"updatePart"`.

---

```
type T1 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;
```

Expand `FunctionPropertyNames<Part>`

```
type T1 = {
  [K in keyof Part]: Part[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}[keyof Part];
```

Expand the `keyof` expressions

```
type T1 = {
  [K in "id" | "name" | "subparts" | "updatePart"]: Part[K] extends Function ? K : never;
}["id" | "name" | "subparts" | "updatePart"];
```

Evaluate the conditional expressions; the [index type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) `Part["updatePart"]` is the only one that satisfies the conditional `extends Function` and so evaluates to `K`, which for the key `updatePart` *is* `"updatePart"`. The others evaluate to `never`.

```
type T1 = {
  id: never;
  name: never;
  subparts: never;
  updatePart: "updatePart";
}["id" | "name" | "subparts" | "updatePart"];
```

Now evaluate the property indexes.

E.g. `{ fieldOne: "abc" }["fieldOne"]` would evaluate to `"abc"`. Whereas `{ fieldTwo: never }["fieldTwo"]` evaluates to `never`.

In our case only indexing with `"updatePart"` evaluates to something other than `never`: the string literal type `"updatePart"`. Everything else evaluates to `never`.

```
type T1 = never | never | never | "updatePart";
```

Which simplifies to

```
type T1 = "updatePart";
```

Comment: Whew, I thought I'd never understand this. Thank you, sir! You're the best!!