# Enforce "keyof object", excluding keys whose values are not a certain type

Tags: typescript

So, I know how to use `keyof ObjectType` to enforce *any* keys of an object. What I want now is to do the same thing, but only include keys whose values match a certain type.

So if I had:

```
interface Foo {
  myProp: string
  someProp: number
  anotherProp: object[]
}
```

I want to get the `keyof Foo` type, but only include keys whose values extend `object[]`.

In other words, is there some way to enforce `keyof (Foo[keyof Foo] extends object[])`, or something to that degree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a helper that makes use of [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) and [index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

```
type ObjectArrayKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object[] ? K : never }[keyof T]
```

For a step by step explanation of the `{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ... ? K : never }[keyof T]` pattern see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63674291/3229534).

Using this helper we can do:

```
interface Foo {
  myProp: string
  someProp: number
  anotherProp: object[]
}

type FooObjArrayKeys = ObjectArrayKeys<Foo>
// type FooObjArrayKeys = "anotherProp"
```

Now `FooObjArrayKeys` equals `"anotherProp"`, which is the only key in the interface that matches.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else coming across this question, I made a generic version: `type KeysOfType<ObjT extends object, ValT> = { [K in keyof ObjT]: ObjT[K] extends ValT ? K : never }[keyof ObjT];`.